# What's the difference between "stall" and "stall out"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, idioms

Can a car engine stall out?

It seems to me that a plane can stall out, but a car can only stall.

Comment: Dictionary.com says:  "(of an engine, car, airplane, etc.) to be stalled or go through the process of stalling (sometimes followed by out )."

Given that definition, I don't think it's exclusive to airplanes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the first ten written instances of *stalled out* in [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stalled%20out%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en), only two involve planes, but most of the rest involve trucks, cars, outboard motors, etc.

So the answer is - Yes, a car engine can stall out, as can lots of things besides planes. OP may be thinking that only planes fall out of the sky when they stall, but I don't think that makes any difference here.

EDIT: Having never heard "stalled out" before, I checked [written instances of 'motor stalled {out}'](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=motor%20stalled,motor%20stalled%20out&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), confirming my suspicion that the "out" version is comparitively 'below the radar'. But it *is* used.

Comment: +1 I had never heard "stalled out" before, neither for planes nor cars.

Comment: also note that a plane stalling is a completely different phenomenon to a car stalling. It's not that the plane's engine stops. It's that the lift coefficient from the wing drops suddenly, either because the plane is moving too slowly, or it's at the wrong angle.

Comment: *My car stalled out at the intersection* would be the normal way to say this, for me (AmE) - that is, I would use *stall out* to refer to a motor stopping, where I would not say just *stall*. I would say *the plane stalled before the crash* because as @slim mentions, this stalling is different; I don't think of them as the same thing.

Comment: Most British people would say "my car stalled at the junction", or "my engine stalled at the junction". I've never heard "stalled out".

Comment: @aedia: Weird. Your distinction seems to be the complete opposite of the one OP was expecting. I'm not sure I understand it - so far as I'm concerned, *"out"* is just something meaninglessly *(and rarely)* tacked on by analogy with *clapped / crapped / knocked out, etc.)* But if you perceive a difference you should post that as an answer to see if anyone else makes the same distinction.

Comment: @slim: The "out" version is far too rare for NGram to give any clue as to whether it's an Americanism. Clearly most Americans don't use it either - but it may well be that those who *do* say it are almost exclusively American.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure but I think the *motor stalled* version may be including the *motor stalled out* instances, inflating the apparent gap in the ngram. I haven't had luck yet searching corpuses, etc. to see how other Americans say this... I also use other "out" car-related verbs like *skid out*, as in, *When I hit the patch of ice my car skidded out, but I was able to recover from the skid.* I thought this was normal ;) and I'm interested to learn that you might not use them the same way!

Comment: @aedia: I don't understand what you mean by *inflating the apparent gap*. I'm pretty certain NGram would include any and all occurrences of *motor stalled out* in the displayed values for *motor stalled*, but since it doesn't show any occurences at all for the former, there's nothing to add. The "gap" is between **zero** for the *out* version, and an estimated 10,400 for the standard version. I think NGram treats any value less than 40 as 0 - but even if there were 39, that's still *almost* non-existent by comparison with 10,400.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're quite right; *motor stalled out* is nonexistent there, and my comment doesn't seem to be relevant to the ngram you mention. I think I was thinking of some other search like *car stalled* vs *car stalled out*, which does have some results for the *out* version, though not that many. After acquiring a healthy dose of "vacation brain," I'm not sure what I meant to say; I probably just wanted to point out in general that it seems one line in the ngram can include occurrences that are graphed in another line, which is one way ngrams could make results visually misleading.

Comment: @aedia: Absolutely. I specifically mentioned that point about interpreting NGram charts in [my answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38678) concerning the prevalence of **close proximity** as a proportion of all instances of the word **proximity**.

Answer (score 4):

Yes an engine can stall out, so can the vehicle that contains it.

In English, *out* is often used as an adverbial intensifier to stress the action represented by the verb. This is certainly the case here. *Out* here serves no semantic purpose other than intensifying the scope of the stalling.

You can also say: my car stalled completely. Here completely is meaningless, because a car  either stalls, or doesn't stall. It can't stall partially. It's not a point along a scale.

Comment: There's no real purpose served by "out". I guess some people say it by association with *crapped out, clapped out, knocked out*, etc. - but [hardly anyone says it anyway](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=motor+stalled%2Cmotor+stalled+out&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), so that may be all it is.