# The adverb "away" for continuity or repetitiveness

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I would like to ask about the adverbial particle "away" meaning continuity or repetitiveness (i.e. not  a location, a distance, a change of position etc.).

When used with some atelic verbs, the meaning is "continually, steadily". This part is quite clear to me.

> Over the past couple years we **worked away** on the car in my spare time.
>
> We sat and **chatted away** till midnight.

The result seems different when **away** is used with short action verbs, it sounds almost exclusively as "repeatedly" to me. Taking a series of actions somehow differs from going on.

> All that can be seen is the silhouette of Macbeth as he **stabs away** with his dagger.
>
> This reddish-brown bird blends in with the leaves that litter the ground as it **pecks away**, looking for insects.
>
> No one says a word to me as I **bang away** on the keyboard.
>
> These feathers serve to brace the woodpecker as it **hammers away**.
>
> While he rechecked the instruments, getting ready for the afternoon's studies, he **licked away** at his ice cream cone.

It requires many peck to feed oneself, it would be hard to eat a cream cone with one lick, killing a king requires several stabs.

So, is there such a strict line between the two meanings or is it just me?

Answer (score 3):

The only way of making an instantaneous action continuous is to repeat it.

Thus *banging away* at a keyboard is made into a continuous stint of action by repeating lots of instantaneous actions.

Consequently you are right that *chat away* means a continuous period of talking and *hammer away* means a number of repeated hammerings, but ***away*** has the same effect in both cases: it marks the action as occurring over an extended period.

Comment: Yup. Effectively, it's just OP who sees *a strict line between the two meanings*. Of course, you could say that *chatting* involves repeated small actions (you say something, then someone else says something, etc.). But you could be chatting in your car, while the engine *hummed away*, where it would be impossible to break that down into a continuously repeated series of actions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **Time** [Metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).
All the sentences in the question refer to passing time by doing various things.

The metaphor theme is ***Time*** *is* ***Motion in Space***. It licenses English speakers to refer to temporal phenomena with words and expressions defined in terms of (their experience of linear motion in) space. E.g,

> *a long/short time*
>   *before/after*
>   *put it behind you*
>   *look forward to it*
>   *years passing*
>   *the coming weeks*
>   *at this point in time.*

That is, *long, short, fore, aft, behind, forward, passing, coming*, and *point* all refer to spatial characteristics, not temporal. They are "places" and "movements" in an individual's "progression through" time. Details in [Fillmore's *Time* lecture](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf).

So with these metaphoric verbs, forming a [phrasal verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/52732/15299) with a particle *away* uses the sense of *time passing, going away, never to return*. And the verb phrases simply comment on how the time was passed.

Thus you can *dance the night away, sleep the day away, while an hour away,* and *drink the years away*.