# Using 'out' with some verbs

Tags: verbs, differences, phrasal-verbs

What is the the difference in meaning when we say

> "help me"

and when we say

> "help me out"

I saw so many verbs like this, and I don't know the exact difference.

Comment: "Help me" could be a request for assistance with some task or a plea for help in an emergency. "Help me out" would be used in the former case but never the latter. See also ttps://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52728/whats-the-meaning-of-out-when-it-comes-after-a-verb?rq=1

Comment: Also @KateBunting Possible Duplicate (specific case of broader question):  english.stackexchange.com/questions/52728

Comment: However, the sweeping statement in the accepted answer there doesn't seem to work in too many cases.

Comment: Mona, as I see it, *out* here likely means "out of a particular situation". "Hey, I have a problem. Help me out." = "Help me out of the problem". (I know that is oversimplifying it, though.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of 'out' when it comes after a verb ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52728/whats-the-meaning-of-out-when-it-comes-after-a-verb)

Comment: This question is too broad for the Stack Exchange format. For example, "ask him/her" is different from "ask him/her out" - in a different way than the request "help me" is different from "help me out". It's a different difference again with "show him" and "show him out".

Comment: i was just confused about this help me and help me out...because i saw it in many cases and i couldnt figure out differences

Answer (score 1):

***Help out*** is a verb collocation which has its own entry in the OED as follows:

> > c. help out (also through): to afford assistance in completing
> >     something; to eke out, supplement. Also absol.
> >
> > 1600   E. Fairfax tr. Tasso Godfrey of Bulloigne ii. iii. 20   Boldest
> >     harts good fortune helpeth out.
> >
> > 1619   E. M. Bolton tr. Florus Rom. Hist. i. iii. 15
> >     Horatius..helping out his valour with his wit.
> >
> > 1709   Tatler No. 101. ⁋7   I must desire my Readers to help me
> >     out..in the Correction of these my Essays.
> >
> > 1711   J. Addison Spectator No. 59. ¶6   She..helps out his Verse, and
> >     furnishes him with Rhymes.
> >
> > 1722   D. Defoe Jrnl. Plague Year 125   They have given me a Bag of
> >     Bread too, and a Salt Fish and some Flesh; so all helps out.
> >
> > 1722   W. Wollaston Relig. of Nature ix. 194   To expect omnipotence
> >     should interpose to help out a bad cause.
> >
> > 1815   Scott Guy Mannering III. v. 86   I will sit wi' you..and help
> >     you out wi' your bottle.
> >
> > 1874   L. B. Walford Mr. Smith (1876) xxx. 261   I looked to you, and
> >     you wouldn't say a word to help me out.
>
> 1917   Dial. Notes 4 413   Holp v. tr., to help. ‘I axed him to holp
>   me out.’

"Out" can be added to other verbs e.g. ***clear out***, ***see out***, ***dig out***, ***look out*** etc but each will have its own nuanced sense.

Comment: yeah it can be added to other verbs too,i was just confused about "help me " and "help me out",thanks for your time

Comment: Apparently, _Collins Cobuild Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs_ has a 'Particles Index'. See [Shoe's answer at 'the seemingly unnecessary "out" in phrasal verbs'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/589594/the-seemingly-unnecessary-out-in-phrasal-verbs).